# How to avoid running my program 10 times for 10 answers?

Tags: java

Once I run my program, it works, but after I input my first integer, it stops returning boolean values and just reads my input back to me. I want it to read multiple integers and tell me if they are prime numbers, how would I do that?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class PrimeCalculator{
      public static boolean IsPrimeNumber(int Number){ //Tells me if it's a prime number
      int Num = Number;
      int x = 0;
      for (int i=0;i<=Num;i++){
        if(Num%(i+1)==0){
          x++;
        }
      }
      Boolean TwoFactors = (x==2);
        return TwoFactors;
      }
      public static void main(String[] args){         // this prints out true/false depending on input
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        Scanner Reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int IntRead = Reader.nextInt();
          System.out.println(IsPrimeNumber(IntRead));
      }
    }
```

Comment: then what is the problem use the loop?

Comment: I input 7, it tells me it's a prime. if I input another integer, it just reads it back to me

Comment: you have to read the integer and pass it to your function again and again using loop place those last 2 condition inside loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use do-while loop

```
int counter = 0;

    do
    {
        counter++;

        int IntRead = Reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println(IsPrimeNumber(IntRead));
    }
    while(counter < 10);
```

or the for loop version:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int IntRead = Reader.nextInt();
        System.out.println(IsPrimeNumber(IntRead));
    }
```

in your **main** method